# Handling deletion of a file while the same file is being modified or deleted in a WriteStream

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, fs, nodejs-stream

When opening a file using `fs.createWriteStream`, how do you handle the case where the underlying file is deleted (eg by a 3rd party, such as `logrotate`)?

None of the normal events seem to fire in this case.

For example:

```
const stream = fs.createWriteStream(filename, { flags: 'a' });

// None of these seem to fire
stream.on('close', () => console.log('CLOSED'));
stream.on('error', () => console.log('ERRORED'));
stream.on('finish', () => console.log('FINISHED'));

stream.write('foo');

// wait for flush...

fs.unlinkSync(filename);

// This doesn't work, but also doesn't error
stream.write('bar');
```

Working example: https://runkit.com/alecgibson/5da4545e76e836001a191ec0

Related:

- https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/21122
- https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options

Notes:

- Node v12.10.0 added the `emitClose` option, which presumably fixes this(?), but I'd like to do this in v10 (LTS)